# Use a string in multiple conditions in a PHP IF statement

Tags: php, string, if-statement

`$mystring` is declared as follows:

```
$mystring = "&& substr($losuj, 0, 1) == 'D' || substr($losuj, 0, 1) == 'K'";
```

I'd like to use `$mystring` (it's created by a loop earlier in my code) in the following statement:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($wynik)) {
    $losuj = $row['wyraz'];
    if (!in_array($losuj, $losowe) 
    $mystring ){.......do something}
}
```

Is it even doable in PHP? I've tried echoing it normally, with `{'$mystring'}`, but I guess you can't interrupt loop statement just like that?

Comment: Why don't you create an array like `$prefixes = array('D', 'K')` and then use `&& in_array($losuj[0], $prefixes)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable using `eval`.
See below a sample using a simpler condition

```
$losowe = array('Kool','Awesome');

$losuj = 'Kool';

$a = 'in_array($losuj,$losowe)';

$mystring = ' && substr($losuj, 0, 1) == "K";';

$condition = eval('return ' . $a . $mystring);

if ($condition == true){
    print 'done' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output

```
done
```

Comment: Kool ;) Happy New Year and thanx for helping!

Comment: Happy New Year to you too @Michalz!